# How can I make my MySQL database work as an SNMP agent with Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, php, snmp

I have one ESP32 temperature sensor sending values to my MySQL database and storing it in the database table. I want to be able to send these values in the database to any SNMP server, can I do that? How?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to use SNMP v2c/3. I tried to do it but Arduino don't have SNMP agent using v2c/3, that's why I want to use this way!

Thanks

Comment: Additionally, please explain, in your original question, how your device is sending messages to the SQL server. If it doesn't support v2/v3, is it sending via syslog/port 514? If that is the case, you may be able to capture that on the SQL as an agent and install a forwarder on the SQL server.